# onload function in jquery not working on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I am new to jquery. I have a simple project. Two pictures stacked on top of each other. I want the page to show the second picture first (so the page needs to start at a certain scroll point) and then the user can scroll up to the first picture. So the code would go something like that

html:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>
        <div id="mainPage" width="100%">
            <img  id="top" src="pic1.jpg" width="100%">
            <img  id="bottom" src="pic2.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#top {
  display: block; 
}

#bottom {
  display: block; 
}
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
 scroll(0, 2300);
}
```

This works when I first load the page, but it doesn't work if I refresh the page (I assume because of something to do with cache?). How can I make the onload function work also when the page is refreshed? Thanks for your time.

Comment: call your onload function in body <body onload="myFunction()">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `jq` why don't you use this type of function on `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop( 3000 );
});
$(window).unload(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop( 3000 );
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#top {
  display: block;
}
#bottom {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainPage" width="100%">
  <img id="top" src="http://drkeyurparmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dummy-article-img-1.jpg" width="100%">
  <img id="bottom" src="http://drkeyurparmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dummy-article-img-1.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I've tried it but it won't sovle the prolem. Like before, it works the first time but it doesn't work if I refresh the page.

Comment: Then you can try `unload()` too.

Answer (score 0):

`load` is page load moment and `beforeunload` is refresh page moment

```
 $(window).on("load",function() {        
    scroll(0, 2300); 
});
 $(window).on("beforeunload",function() {        
    scroll(0, 2300); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So if it's working first time, your code is ok. But seems you have to force to delete page cache.

Try this options:

Add this meta tags to your head and give it a try.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

If you want to control by js the delete of the cache, you can try making a simple js function:

```
deleteCache(){
   window.location = window.location.href+'?eraseCache=true';
}
```